# MONGOOSE - ObjectId reference to collection VS Array of collection

Tags: mongoose

Well, I'm new to mongodb/mongoose so some of this concepts are still a bit messy in my head. Can anyone explain me the difference between the following:

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String,
    groups: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }]
});
```

and

```
var GroupsSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
});

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String,
    groups  : [GroupsSchema ]
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the Mongoose ways of supporting the [embed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-embedding) or [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-referencing) options when modeling your data.

The first case uses references, where the `groups` array field of each `Person` doc contains `ObjectId` values that identify the `_id` of the related `Group` docs in a separate collection.  This is effectively storing a set of foreign keys in `groups`.

In the second case, the `groups` array directly contains (i.e. embeds) the related group docs.  There won't be a separate collection for groups in this case and it's up to your application to ensure that any duplicated group data in the arrays is consistently updated.